# ngx bootstrap sortable in custom template usage

Tags: html, angular, web, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-6 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
    <bs-sortable
      [(ngModel)]="objectGroups"
      filedName="displayName"
      itemClass="sortable-item"
      itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"
      placeholderItem="Drag here"
      placeholderClass="placeholderStyle"
      wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper"
    ></bs-sortable>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is what i implement for sortable, it include my api data named as objectGRoups

i need to make this sortable work on the icon placed just before the objectgroup.name.

```
<tr>
      <td>
        <svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 32 32" aria-hidden="true">
          <path
            d="M10 6H14V10H10zM18 6H22V10H18zM10 14H14V18H10zM18 14H22V18H18zM10 22H14V26H10zM18 22H22V26H18z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>
          <lib-render-icon [iconColor]="obj?.iconColor" *ngIf="obj.iconId" [iconId]="obj.iconId"></lib-render-icon>
        </span>
        {[{ obj.displayName }]}</td>
</tr>
```

just on the svg icon, but do not have any idea for the same. how do i implement sortable in the svg icon isted of creating new template